# How do I automatically resize input fields in a form?

Tags: html, css, forms, input-field

I'm trying to make my registration form responsive for mobile devices but I got a little problem with the resizing of my input fields,

I made a jsfiddle to show the situation:
https://jsfiddle.net/ntvrhLpe/

I would like that if the width is smaller than 540px the input fields automatically resize to full width with a margin of 10px at both sides.

I already tried some things but nothing works:

```
input[type=text], input[type=password], input[type=email]{
margin-left:10px;
margin-right:10px;
width:100%;
}
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your initial CSS for inputs

```
input[type=text], input[type=password], input[type=email] {
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    padding: 8px 6px;
    height: 38px;
    width:250px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Then in your media query:

```
input[type=text], input[type=password], input[type=email] {
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    width: 100%;
}

fieldset {
    padding: 10px;
}
```

You will get it

You should get satisfaction

Comment: Only problem is that the height of the input field is now changed?

Comment: The `box-sizing: border-box;` allows you to set a `width` even if a `padding` is set without disturbing the Math of width

Answer (score 0):

You have not set the width is your css ( it was not in the fiddle although you have mention it in you question ! )

Please see https://jsfiddle.net/rwbLmex2/

```
@media (max-width: 540px) {
label {
    text-align:left;
    width:180px;
    float:left;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-left:20px;
} 
input[type=text], input[type=password], input[type=email]{
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-right:10px;
    width : 100%
}
}
```

By the way I recommend to use a CSS framework like bootstrap which handle all them for you !